# View last results on Stack Overflow (Or other website) after reload page

Tags: javascript, html, partial-page-refresh

It's my first HTML/javascript question which I raised on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362333/show-previous-results-after-reload) without results yet,
On [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362333/show-previous-results-after-reload) I reload my tags page which displays questions related to my selected tags.

If I want to go back to the previous results/page with a reload, then a question I wanted to check isn't possible because it's going back in history to a different page (or a blank page).

Can I go to the previous view? Is it impossible?

Sometimes questions are deleted or have changed tags so it's hard to find them.

Is it possible in javascript/HTML to view last results?

Comment: Is your question about stackoverflow or HTML? Seems a little unclear.

Comment: Reload is not location change. History works when navigaton occurs. But more important is browser cache itc. There is one cached page per unique link. So if you would cache same page in many versions, it should also generate unique id to path (for example timestamp) everytime..

Comment: @Craig, I want to know if it can be done in stackoverflow site, maybe by using a javascript or other component that will save my previous results

Comment: @bigless so you suggest instead of reload to open a new tab/window to keep old results? or is there another way?

Comment: You ask question related to behaviour of this site in section javascript/html. I described how to prevent reloading browser cache during page reload in general. How is this applicable to Stackoverflow is another thing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been in the same situation many times, wishing to see what I just saw but the internet has changed out from under me. (It actually happened while I was researching this answer...) Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1309/

---

Let's talk a little about **what this question is actually asking?** The *example* given in this question is this very site, SO. But the *purpose* can apply to any website with dynamic information. As a user browses through information, an often used pattern is to link into more specific details. When the user moves back to the general list, it sometimes occurs that new information has been added, or old information removed, or just generally moved about. In those cases, it can be difficult for the user to navigate back to information they may have wanted to look at or they have looked at but now lost the link to. **We ask what can be done to make this UX better** both in the user habits and the website design.

I think this question truly does apply to both meta and non-meta, since there are many aspects: what can SO specifically do, as website, to improve their UX (the meta question); what could developers of sites do in general to improve UX in this regard; and what can user do to better utilize their technology or improve their workflow to improve their UX without special consideration from a website. Let's talk about what the user can do first.

---

#### What can a user do?

In some senses, **this should be a simple task**. All the browser would need to do is keep a record of the current DOM in it's cache when moving to a new page, then on back press, load the cached DOM as it stood when you last looked at it. But what do browsers actually do?

1. **Browsers won't consistently help you right now** by default. The answer by [Stephan P](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39670500/8684601) gives us some insight. Essentially, going 'back' could result in a number of different things from loading the cached resources like I described above, to reloading some of the resources, to just refetching everything. And this is all decided by the arcane machinations of your browser. **You have basically no say in what happens**. (Except of course when you use one of the many methods to forcibly skip cache and reload all the recourses, but there doesn't seem to by any method to forcibly load from cache). So, no dice there.
2. The **closest browser functionality** I was able to find is the setting to load from cache when [offline in Chrome](https://lifehacker.com/load-cached-pages-in-chrome-without-internet-by-enablin-1705985239). But this would require us to constantly switch between connecting and disconnecting from the internet while browsing. Which is **not very helpful**.
3. The above point actually just proves that this should be 100% possible,
   if **we could just look at our browser's cache of the page**. Which we can! [GolfWolf](https://superuser.com/a/411526) lets us know about the handy `chrome://cache` address that let's us view the complete contents of our browser's cache! ***Unfortunately,* it is all in hex, so not super useful for browsing...**
4. There are [tools](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2012/01/viewing-chrome-cache-easy-way.html) that will **convert the hex dump to a viewable webpage** as [Senseful](https://superuser.com/a/575410) points us to. But I think, going into your cache, finding the old page, copying hex over to a translater, then viewing your page is **not a very friendly workflow** for regular browsing.

**So, our browser is basically useless for what we are trying to accomplish.** We only have a few options:

1. [Write our own browser](https://www.chromium.org/Home)
2. Something very custom...

   A. *One* potential would be to **set up a proxy of sorts**, that hard caches all the pages that went through it and returns from cache when you went back in your browser. Perhaps a simple browser extension button to click to send a message to the proxy to clear its cache?

   B. While we're talking about *crazy ideas*... It could be possible to **make a webpage that loads pages in `iframe`s** and attempts to intercept link clicks and instead of opening in the same `iframe` opens a new `iframe` to the new page and just hides the old `iframe` in its previous state, so when you go 'back' it just unhides your old page. But that is ***super* cludgy and will break a lot of stuff** with all those discontinuities. (and don't forget, not all links open a new page, there's a lot of ways this plan could go wrong).

**Outside of actually solving this**, what could we do to **mitigate or work around our problems**? ...Never leave a webpage... ever...
In all seriousness, **this is my workflow**: open the main page, **open all links in new tabs** (You can usually `cmd/ctrl-click` to quickly open a link in a new tab), **keep all the tabs open until I've finished.**

---

#### What can a website do?

**Several things.** There are many strategies that can be used to make information traversable, and they all have their own benefits and ramifications. This is not an exhaustive list:

1. The site can implement **custom urls with parameters** for everything that could affect rendering of information. Google search does this. In this way going back to a link (or just sharing a link to a different person) will result in loading the page in the same deterministic way as before. This can be used to great success, but also can result in inordinately long links.
2. The site can use **cookies** or **local storage** to keep track of where you are to restore your state when you return to a previous page.
3. The site can **create its own history** for you to browse. This is similar to what SO does now in other aspects, but taken to the extreme. Basically, record every action, every comment, every view, every post, absolutely everything. Then let the user browse through this history of things (obviously with lots of sorting and filtering options) to let them sift down to what they are looking for. i.e. "What was that post I was looking at yesterday? ...*searching*... Oh here it is!"

Each of these are **huge** topics on their own. *Way* outside scope of an answer here on SO.

---

**TL;DR**

- A user can't do much of anything that isn't either a lot of work or breaks flow in one way or another, or both.
- A website can do *a lot* of things to ease the user's pain. But there's no silver bullet. Only lots of work to make a good UX.

Comment: +1 for describing every possible aspects, but the answer is too long to read through, and I think i am the only one who read it full :P, make it concise and make the question clear a bit and probably shorten the conclusion :)

Comment: It certainly is a meaty answer. I've tried to edit it to be easier to consume. more bullet point-y, easily skim-able. But it is still a beast. I"m welcome to any edits that could improve the wording of the answer to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play with the ids to go back only with the browser, but if the question is deleted I think there's no way to catch its content if you don't use a web crawler software :/

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630484/`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{ID}/ (it's an autoincremental id)

Comment: But I'm talking about general page as https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+is%3Aquestion&tab=newest

Comment: This might work better as an answer to the meta question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362333/show-previous-results-after-reload. But overall I think you should improve the answer (how should the user keep track of these question ids? could SO do something to make accessing/remembering these question ids easier?)