# Headless Chrome with Python suspends when trying to download a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm using Python, Jupyter, Selenium webdriver and headless Chrome (with Canary) on Mac.

I wrote a script that scrapes a very old website,
In order to download a file from that website I need to click on several buttons which eventually lead me to a button that once clicked it downloads a CSV file

The problem is that when headless Chrome tries to download the target file it suspends and does nothing (i.e. doesn't download the required file) even though the script finished running (and yes I did close it at the end of the script)

I tried:

- Downloading other files (from different websites) and headless Chrome seems to download them without any problems (I enabled the headless chrome option to download files successfully)
- Taking snapshots of the websites to make sure it's navigating correctly to the download page (and yeah, its navigating correctly)
- Modifying the user agent (it appears to be using the user agent I expect it to)
- Running the exact same code without the headless option - it downloads the file successfully with regular chrome
- Changing plugins and languages JS script on the driver by using `driver.execute_script(js_that_changes_plugins_and_langs)` but I'm not quite sure how to check if it's actually executing it or not (and it's still not working)

Problems I'm facing:

- I can't find a way to get just the last download URL because it seems to be using some unique IDs generated along the way (it's given when you go to the homepage and when you are navigating between pages in the site) so for every session it's going to change
- The navigation URLs seem to be originating from iframes inside the homepage (and also in the following URLs) and I'm not quite sure how to inspect the Javascript it's generating

I don't have any problem providing the website URL but:

- You have to go through like ~6 clicks on different pages in order to just get to the last page with the download button. These clicks are not intuitive and it will take a lot in order to explain how to navigate to where I want
- This site is not in English which will make it even harder to explain how to navigate

I need it to be headless as opposed to regular Chrome since the machine where we want to run the code is very weak and cannot run the chrome GUI

So my question is: does anyone knows what may the problem? or at least, how can I debug it?

This is more or less the code that I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def enable_download_in_headless_chrome(driver, download_dir):
        """
        there is currently a "feature" in chrome where
        headless does not allow file download: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481
        This method is a hacky work-around until the official chromedriver support for this.
        Requires chrome version 62.0.3196.0 or above.
        """

        # add missing support for chrome "send_command"  to selenium webdriver
        driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/' + driver.session_id + '/chromium/send_command')

        params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
        command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)
        print("response from browser:")
        for key in command_result:
            print("result:" + key + ":" + str(command_result[key]))

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('remote-deubgging-port=9222')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-popup-blocking')
chrome_options.add_argument('enable-logging')
download_dir = # some path here
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
enable_download_in_headless_chrome(driver, download_dir)
ok_button = driver.find_element_by_id('the-button-name')
ok_button.click()
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried adding `user-agent`? There are also other techniques for detecting headless Chrome to let server decide what to do (for e.g. interrupting the download), you might want to look at https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/

Comment: Also have a look [at this](https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/), which is essentially a followup on what @hurturk suggested.

Comment: At which point does it hang specifically? after which line of code? Have you checked the 'download' dir that the user the browser process runs under has write permissions?

Comment: you may monitor the requests with zaproxy for debugging purpose.

Comment: I did try using the user-agent by adding `user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')` but it still doesnt work, I'll need to make sure that the other options suggested in the link you provided are also set properly

it hangs right after the click. I see the headless chrome is open (when I alt tab) but nothing happens. 

I'll have a look at zaproxy
thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: Actually, you are adding the wrong header from the example (see it has HeadlessChrome string), just in case, please try with `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Without the link it is difficult to tell.
There are a few different ways how a website can start a download. Can you post a screenshot of the Network tab while you manually download the file?

Comment: @hurturk I'll give try using the header you provided and let you know if it helps. Regarding the link - its not that I have any problem providing you with the link but, it takes like 10 clicks in order to get to the relevant download location (and you cant get to it directly since it uses a session id and other stuff) and its also not in english so, just explaining where to click will take quite a lot of work

Comment: Did you try to execute your script via Python Shell in **headed** mode (with the dev-tool opened on the console), doing it step by step so as to see exactly how/where it fails?

Comment: Can you try debugging the headless browser launched manually? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017982/debugging-with-headless-browser/46018351#46018351. Take it to that page and see exactly what is happening. It may be a javascript error that might be happening for that download and if that is the case you will see it in the console

Comment: If I run it in headed mode it downloads everything as expected. when I enable headless mode it stops working

Comment: this is a known issue with headless chrome. check this [link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5159)

Comment: I did see this already, I am able to download files from other websites just not specifically from this site

Answer (score 0):

As you do not provide the URL from where you download its guessing work. Target most likely has a recapta-like wall installed to prevent scraping. So be sure you don't hit this "recapta" wall and if you do implement code that notifies you to perform a manual task for granting access.

For js this solution was given by zavodnyuk [here](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/174):

> try to set custom User-Agent with compatible one (e.g. from your real browser).
>   capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome', chromeOptions: {args: [ "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36", "--headless", "--disable-gpu" ] } worked for selenium/protractor on js

I hope this hints you in the right direction as there is not much about it described for python on the internet.

EDIT based on comment1:

In basic debugging mode I rely on print-statements at the start of possible candidate defs. Where I say printstatement it can be a write line to file as well. Not relying on thrid party fancy packages because I want to learn from the code most of the times and then is above approach time consuming but well worth the effort of spend time. For example how I bluntly debug:

```
def header_inspect(self, ID, action, data):
    print  'header_inspect, ID : %s\n, action : %s\nprocess-data : %s' % (ID, action, data)
```

Comment: The target doesnt seem to have any recaptcha like mechanisms (that I'm aware of). Also when I take the snapshot right before clicking the download button it shows the button properly so I don't think that is the problem. I'll try to check all the webdriver parameters before sending the request and see if anything looks weird. I was hoping to be able to understand what is exactly making the webdriver suspend and never terminate

Comment: Do you happen to know if its possible to see debug logs when running the headless chrome code with python? If so, where? When it suspends I'm not sure what is it stuck on

Comment: my approach in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are too many moving parts here. If you really need selenium, and all others - well - that is OK. However I would start with something as simple as possible.

On Python 2.7 I was using [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) - that way I was able to mimic whole communication with the server. Today that is not best option, since python 3.X is the way to go. I'll describe how I was working with this kind of problems. Just to give you better picture, and then I'll try to describe possible tools.

So typical case was login, go over the page, turn some switches, and trigger download, or fetch content and process it with [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). To start, you need to see what information is exchanged. Go to development tools in your web browser, and choose network tab. *Perhaps you know that, but this step is mandatory, and I'm suppose to write general answer.* Then do your normal work - just login, and do other steps. All things that the server takes care off must be transmitted, so you can see it as network requests. Mechanize was good since I was able to prepare `dict`, and sent it as a `post` request to the page. Writing about `post` - **typical mistake is posting to the page address**. So if you ware visited `index.html`, you are doing `post` on that page, while server expects it to be sent to `add_user_data.html` and after that you ware redirected. Things like session id, can be supported by header entry, or cookie - just look at network communication for the pattern.

As I wrote Python 2.7 is going to be discontinued. Mechanize is not available for Python 3.x, so other tools should be used. You can look for mechanize alternatives, and look what is OK for you. Typical answer is [scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). That is a bit different tool used more to scrap web pages. So if you plan something bigger maybe that is best option. If you need single script - I would start with [httpie](https://httpie.org/). Command line tool / python package, good OSX support, you can [send form](https://httpie.org/doc#regular-forms), [session management](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie#sessions) is also available. I'm using it everyday, however my server is stateless.

I would be more then happy providing exact examples, but without server information that is not possible. Can you please attach dump of your sample session? Anonymize it, and I'll provide sample sample, or maybe other tool can be petter?

Comment: Not familiar with mechanize but the problem with this website is that you have to go through roughly 10 clicks (and you can't bypass these steps) so I have to simulate a user that actually clicks all these buttons

Comment: @Gideon that is not a problem. It can be 5, 10, or what ever clicks - that is script. Right click + Inspect, and then choose 'network` tab. To start tracking you need F5 to refresh. Having whole session you can select requests, and store them. They call it har. That is JSON file with whale content. From that you can perform all of that with `requests`, or `httpie` - up to you. Just edit question, and share something. Other option is to point to public side, and we can work that way.

Comment: I may be wrong here but the URLs that are generated along the clicks are given a unique ID. These IDs are given from a code in an iframe in the home page, this basically means I cannot just hardcode a request to the end URL. Got any idea on how I can inspect that iframe?

Comment: Not likely. In general that is possible, but also quite expensive from server side. You can have session, and that is identified by cookie, or part of url... Be sure to extract it, and then use in next requests. Since I have no idea about context - hard to say more.

Answer (score 0):

With no specific information, it looks like the only advises that we can give you will somehow be related to how you can understand what is going on.

What about proceeding step by step ***manually*** in ***headed mode*** for debugging purpose?  The bet here is that your problem lies in the fact of automating your task rather than being headless.

Execute your script with all your imports and functions definitions (e.g. `enable_download_in_headless_chrome`), using none of those. Actually, do so until `download_dir = # some path here`, and then, in the Python Shell, type

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Now interact manually with your browser and open the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) and go the [Console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/images/console-drawer.png). Make sure that errors [will be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMz3g.png). Let's continue and type the rest of your commands

```
>>> enable_download_in_headless_chrome(driver, download_dir)
>>> ...
>>> ok_button.click()
```

What does it say?

Comment: If I run the entire script in a headed mode (comment the headless line only) it goes through the entire process and downloads the file successfully. Once I add the headless option its when it finishes the script but the chrome canary suspends and doesnt close (and doesnt download the file I need)

Comment: @Gideon. Silly point: did you try to `time.sleep` (or better to `WebDriverWait`) some seconds before clicking your download button? Headless mode is sometime so reactive that it creates inconsistencies during browsing.

Comment: lol, yeah I did. In my headed script I also do some sleeps in order for everything to work then when I switch to headless I still have to sleep on so yeah

Comment: @Gideon. Did you consider some  counter-strike strategies by fulfilling some JavaScript variables during headless browsing? [These elements](http://antoinevastel.github.io/bot%20detection/2017/08/05/detect-chrome-headless.html) for example.

Comment: I tried the user agent, not the rest. I'll check and get back to you

Comment: I tried doing: `driver.execute_script(javascript_code_that_adds_plugins_and_languages)` and it still didnt work - not sure how to make sure it is actually injecting the javascript, got any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

try     String downloadFilepath ="\\sd-";

chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);